# upper() on a queryset

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to get the uppercased values_list in the below query?

```
dict(Territory.objects.values_list('name'.upper(),'code')) # in pseudocode
```

Or do I need to do a list comprehension?

Answer (score 0):

```
dict([(name.upper(), code.upper()) for name,code in Territory.objects.values_list('name','code')])
```